# Sign in with google, but not google+

Tags: php, google-authentication

I have a web app where I'm trying to allow my users to sign in with google as a registration method.

On their API I found: https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/ But that only looks like you can sign in with google+. I know they're basically the same thing, but if a user who doesn't have google+ clicks that to sign in, it asks them to create a google+ account.

Is there a way to sign in with just google and not google+?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for Google oAuth API:-

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but it says it's deprecated and you should use the new one...

Comment: So use the new one (oAuth2). Updated the link for you.